# Why when flagging can't I choose any StackExchange site the question should belong?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

It is another time I run into this issue, this time on the *Stack Overflow* there was a question clearly concerning math only. The author event tagged it this way.

So as I'm reviewing it, I would like to flag it, so I follow the appropriate path:

`it should be closed for another reason...` -> `off-topic because...` -> `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` and... all I can choose is

- meta.stackoverflow.com
- superuser.com
- tex.stackexchange.com
- dba.stackexchange.com
- sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Why can't I flag that it belongs to `math.stackexchange.com`? Or any other *Stack Exchange* site?
Because now I can't see any other appropriate cause to flag that question and no moderator can see it.

PS. The question in this exercise is

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013965/can-i-do-reverse-curve-fitting-operation-of-2nd-order-curve-y-abxcx2

Comment: Moderators can move posts to any site. However I notice you don't even have an account on math.se so how can you be sure it's a suitable question for them?

Comment: @JonW So I have to have an account to visit the site? Not really. And, just look at the question.

Besides that, it's a duplicate and now I do have my answer :)

Comment: You don't have to have an account, no. But lots of people suggest migrations to totally unsuitable sites because they don't have knowledge of suitable posts for that site. Not that this is such a case, but as a mod on another SE site (UX) I always look at the flaggers rep on the target site as a measure of whether or not the question is suitable for migration.

Comment: @JonW I get it. I understand the reason for it and I will have to live with it :) but more seriously - if I can flag it so the moderator could see it, that's totally fine with me.